# POST getting converted to GET across OS

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, struts-1

I'm facing a very weird kind of problem while running my application.

When I hit a website and login to my application, the POST is getting converted to GET automatically. Since all the request parameters are getting lost due to this, the page shows up an error screen. 
**This issue happens in IE-8 (Windows 7), but works absolutely fine in IE-8(Windows XP).**
How is the OS involved in this? Have anyone faced such issues? This issue happens in IE-9 as well.

Kindly refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096343/post-method-getting-converted-to-get-in-ie-9) issue as well. Any solutions would be really helpful.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was happening due to a security setting in IE in Windows 7. 

There is an option of Enabling/Disabling **protected mode** in IE of Windows-7. This is a new feature present in IE of Vista/Windows-7 and this option is enabled by default for “Internet” zone and “Local Intranet” zone(or any one of them). Disabling at these 2 places solved the issue.

Tools -> Internet Options -> Security -> Internet/Local Intranet -> Uncheck on the "Enable protected mode" option.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to this party, but I just ran into this as well, and it made me crazy.  IE (only) was turning a POST into a GET, which took running Fiddler to determine.  This thread got me part way there, but the protected mode wasn't the deal.  It turns out one site was in the Internet zone (the page making the post) and the other (receiving the post) was in the Intranet Zone.  By adding the calling page to either Intranet Zone or Trusted Sites, IE stopped turning the POST into a GET.  It appears that you can't call up the zone stack without IE turning the POST into a get, but you can call *down*.  The big tip for us (we opened the POST in a new window (target=_blank)) was that when calling from Internet to Intranet, the new page opened in a new IE window, but when configured "correctly", the new popup will open in a new tab (the expected behavior).